# org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered org.infinispan Exception?

Tags: java, tomcat6

i have my application deployed as myApp1 on tomcat 6 service. Due to some requirement, i copied myApp1 and pasted under webapp as myApp2.Now i restarted tomcat
and hit my url for myApp1. Worked fine . But on hitting the url for app2 , i get org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered org.infinispan
.Below is the root cause section in exception stack trace

```
  root cause 

    org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered org.infinispan
org.infinispan.jmx.JmxUtil.buildJmxDomain(JmxUtil.java:73)
org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration.updateDomain(CacheManagerJmxRegistration.java:92)
org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration.buildRegistrar(CacheManagerJmxRegistration.java:86)
org.infinispan.jmx.AbstractJmxRegistration.registerMBeans(AbstractJmxRegistration.java:46)
org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration.start(CacheManagerJmxRegistration.java:62)
org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.start(DefaultCacheManager.java:637)
org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:319)
org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:283)
org.xwiki.cache.infinispan.internal.InfinispanCacheFactory.initialize(InfinispanCacheFactory.java:134)
org.xwiki.component.embed.InitializableLifecycleHandler.handle(InitializableLifecycleHandler.java:39)
org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:295)
org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:358)
org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:324)
org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.lookup(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:147)
org.xwiki.component.internal.DefaultComponentManager.lookup(DefaultComponentManager.java:72)
org.xwiki.cache.internal.DefaultCacheManager.getCacheFactory(DefaultCacheManager.java:79)
org.xwiki.cache.internal.DefaultCacheManager.getCacheFactory(DefaultCacheManager.java:61)
com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getCacheFactory(XWiki.java:5887)
```

For the information,I am running the tomcat as service.

Comment: Do you happen to know the solution for latest Infinispan versions (e.g. [v12](https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-12.1.xsd)), which don't have `allowDuplicateDomains` attribute anymore? I have the same issue when Spring Boot tests are run in a row in the same JVM – the 2nd Spring Boot run triggers the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to your two applications running at the same time, and trying to use the same resource. From the looks of the error message 'infinispan' registers a JMX domain on startup, and does not allow multiple instances of this.

From [google](https://community.jboss.org/message/600218): If you want to allow multiple instances configured with same JMX domain enable `allowDuplicateDomains` attribute in `globalJmxStatistics` config element

Comment: If this happens, you might want to check if tests get executed in parallel. For Maven Surefire set `reuseForks` to false.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Spring Boot + [Infinispan starter](https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/spring_boot/starter.html) here is the way to switch off JMX:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class InfinispanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InfinispanGlobalConfigurationCustomizer globalCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.jmx().disable();
    }
}
```