# org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered with hibernate-infinispan on JBoss

Tags: hibernate, exception, jboss, infinispan

I have a question partly related to [org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered org.infinispan Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295751/org-infinispan-jmx-jmxdomainconflictexception-domain-already-registered-org-inf) with the difference, that I use hibernate 4.3.6 in JBoss 7.1.1. I have two applications, which have persistence.xml roughly looking like that:

```xml
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="..." transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=...)</jta-data-source>
        <class>...</class>
        <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.container"
                value="hibernate-exp" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The exception occurs, when the persistence unit of the second application gets loaded by hibernate. Now the solutions from the net often mention to add this to infinispan-config:

```xml
<globalJmxStatistics allowDuplicateDomains="true" />
```

However this config file is a part of hibernate-infinispan module so I cannot simply modify it. This [issue seems to be fixed](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-2886), but I am unfortunately restricted to use infinispan 6. Any suggestions?

**edit:** I would expect the JBoss AS cache manager to be used. That's why `hibernate.cache.infinispan.container` is set and `hibernate-ext` is configured like this in the `domain.xml`:

```
<domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
    <profiles>
        <profile name="full">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
                <cache-container name="hibernate-exp" default-cache="local-query">
                    <local-cache name="entity">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="@hibernate.expireable.eviction.strategy@" max-entries="@hibernate.expireable.eviction.max_entries@"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="@hibernate.expireable.expiration.max_idle@" interval="@hibernate.expireable.expiration.interval@"/>
                        <locking concurrency-level="@hibernate.expireable.locking.concurrency_level@"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="local-query">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="@hibernate.expireable.eviction.strategy@" max-entries="@hibernate.expireable.eviction.max_entries@"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="@hibernate.expireable.expiration.max_idle@" interval="@hibernate.expireable.expiration.interval@"/>
                        <locking concurrency-level="@hibernate.expireable.locking.concurrency_level@"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <local-cache name="timestamps">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                    </local-cache>
                </cache-container>
            </subsystem>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</domain>
```

However the omission of `hibernate.cache.infinispan.container` occurs an exception:

```
org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
```

I have no idea why this error occurs, since hibernate-infinispan, infinispan-commons and infinispan-core are on hibernate's classpath. I'm not sure, but this may be somehow related to the fact, that I deploy two different hibernate versions into JBoss (4.0.1 and 4.3.6). The configuration without the property works with 4.0.1, but not with 4.3.6.

If I use `org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory` i get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:478)
```

...because `org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory` from jboss-as-jpa-hibernate4 is wired to `RegionFactory` from Hibernate 4.0.1. The used `SettingsFactory` is from Hibernate 4.3.6 and it tries to cast it to `RegionFactory` from its own module.

**edit2:** With the help of debugger I found out, that if I use Hibernate 4.0.1, the property `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` is set to `org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.SharedInfinispanRegionFactory` although I don't have that property set in my persistence.xml. These properties are held in the mappings for example if the debugger halts in `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(XClass, Map<XClass, InheritanceState>, Mappings)`.

That property gets additionally set by JBoss in `HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.addProviderDependencies(...)`:

```
public class HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor implements PersistenceProviderAdaptor {
    private static final String DEFAULT_REGION_FACTORY = SharedInfinispanRegionFactory.class.getName();
    //...
    public void addProviderDependencies(ServiceRegistry registry, ServiceTarget target, ServiceBuilder<?> builder, PersistenceUnitMetadata pu) {
        Properties properties = pu.getProperties();
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty(AvailableSettings.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE))) {
            //...
            String regionFactory = properties.getProperty(AvailableSettings.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY);
            if (regionFactory == null) {
                regionFactory = DEFAULT_REGION_FACTORY;
                properties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, regionFactory);
            }
            //...
 }
```

The class `SharedInfinispanRegionFactory` is the one, which uses cache settings from the `domain.xml` so if I would use `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory` these setting wouldn't apply. But since I cannot use `SharedInfinispanRegionFactory` due to the `ClassCastException` I might need to implement my own `RegionFactory`.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the configuration file by setting the property `hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg`, but I don't think that's the proper solution, because this means that you create a new instance of Infinispan *cache manager*.

When you use 2LC in JBoss AS, you should grab the *cache manager* that is managed by the AS, being able to set configuration in your `standalone.xml` etc., therefore either not setting the `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` property at all or setting that to `org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory` (regrettably I am not sure how this integrates in such an old version).

Comment: This makes sense, but please see my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the fix provided for CDI ([ISPN-2886](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-2886)) probably won't help you. It is very likely that JBoss AS configuration requires some Infinispan caches for session replication and then you requested additional caches for JPA 2nd level caching. Those two create separate Cache Managers and cause a clash.

According to [JBoss AS 7 manual](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingtheHibernate4JPApersistenceprovider), you shouldn't need to specify any additional properties when using Hibernate 4 and Infinispan (both are shipped by default).

Could you please try removing all those additional properties?